# Select from table type of objects

Tags: sql, oracle, select, plsql

I have the  below types

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD" IS OBJECT  (
  CharacteristicID              NUMBER,
  NewValue              VARCHAR2(200 Char),
  NewValueName      VARCHAR2(200 Char)
);


 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE "CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE" IS 
  TABLE OF CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD;
```

and the below Procedure

```
DECLARE 

characteristic CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE:=CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_TABLE(

      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(2,'ZIKA','ZIKA'),
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(3,'MIGO','MIGO'),
      CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(4,'ZAG','ZAG')

);

char_record CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD;

BEGIN


END;
```

and i need to select from characteristic record with CharacteristicID = 3 into the char_record variable

Comment: Please don't post the same question more than once.  Be patient if you don't get the answer you need right away.

Answer (score 0):

This returns a copy of the record, not the same record

```
SELECT CLONE_PRODUCT_CHAR_RECORD(CharacteristicID, NewValue, NewValueName)
  INTO char_record
  FROM TABLE(characteristic)
 WHERE CharacteristicID = 3;
```

If you want the record itself, instead of a copy, declare a variable, `row_num` say, to hold the row number of the row, use a query to find that, and then use this row number to find the record from the table:

```
SELECT rn
  INTO row_num
  FROM (SELECT CharacteristicID, ROWNUM AS rn
          FROM TABLE(characteristic))
 WHERE CharacteristicID = 3;

char_record := characteristic(row_num);
```